# How to modifying already designed metro style app to support all screen resolutions?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm new to app developed and in my first attempt i tried to design a win8 metro style app. During whole design process i took default screen resolution of 1336X768 and never tested my app in other resolutions.After completing whole development process, now when i change resolution of  the simulator and run the app the results are shocking!!!, few buttons are going out of screen, characters in the text box are missing, completely the UI of the app is getting messed up. Is there a way now to modify so that the app supports all the screen resolutions?

Comment: Yes, stop using absolute positioning. Of course, eventually the screen is just *too small*, but I doubt you've reached that yet. Which layout controls are you using?

Comment: The layout control i used is GridSystem. Where can i change positioning settings?

Comment: Is everything you currently have set up as margins within that grid? Start by actually using the rows and columns, and make sure they aren't hard-coded widths/heights.